# Android Development - ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.DATA won't update with new Skype name

Tags: android

I am passing a string to my function that is supposed to UPDATE various parts of an existing contact. Name, Phone and Email I am able to update, but the Skype name I cannot seem to get working...

I pass a string to the following function, it parses it into am array, and then those array pieces are used in the function...for example, let's say I am passing the following string: #skype#|7|hawleytronics|hawleytronic

The string is parsed via the "|" delimiter, with the parts as follows: #skype# designates the part of the contact record we want to update, the 7 is the RAW_ID of the contact, the hawleytronics is the OLD Skype name and the hawleytronic is the NEW Skype name that we want to update the contact to. My code for this section is below. Please help me in understanding why it won't update. BTW, no errors are thrown and it acts as if it updated but the record does not get updated at all. Name, Phone and Email are updated in similar fashion.

```
//SKYPE...
        if(dataString.startsWith("#skype#|")){
            Log.e("EAM", "DATASTRING DOES CONTAIN: "+"#skype#|");
            String rawContactID = "";
            String[] contactData = dataString.split("\\|");
            Log.e("EAM", "contactData[1]: "+contactData[1]);
            Log.e("EAM", "contactData Length: "+contactData.length);
            rawContactID = contactData[1];
            Log.e("EAM", "TOTAL STRING: "+contactData);
            String newSkypeName = contactData[3];
            Log.e("EAM", "contactData[1]: "+contactData[1]);
            Log.e("EAM", "contactData[2]: "+contactData[2]);
            Log.e("EAM", "contactData[3]: "+contactData[3]);

            ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
            Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);

            builder.withSelection(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + "=?" + " AND " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.PROTOCOL + "=?" + " AND " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.DATA + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(rawContactID), String.valueOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.PROTOCOL_SKYPE), String.valueOf(contactData[2])});             
            builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.DATA, newSkypeName);

            // Update
            try
            {
                getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
                Log.e("EAM", "SKYPE NAME SAVED AS: "+contactData[3].trim());
                savedContactName = contactData[3];
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:savedContactSkype();");
                    }
                });
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hah! I forgot this piece of code...it goes right after "builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.DATA, newSkypeName);"

**ops.add(builder.build());**

So the full code for this part of the function is now:

```
//SKYPE...
            if(dataString.startsWith("#skype#|")){
                Log.e("EAM", "DATASTRING DOES CONTAIN: "+"#skype#|");
                String rawContactID = "";
                String[] contactData = dataString.split("\\|");
                Log.e("EAM", "contactData[1]: "+contactData[1]);
                Log.e("EAM", "contactData Length: "+contactData.length);
                rawContactID = contactData[1];
                Log.e("EAM", "TOTAL STRING: "+contactData);
                String newSkypeName = contactData[3];
                Log.e("EAM", "contactData[1]: "+contactData[1]);
                Log.e("EAM", "contactData[2]: "+contactData[2]);
                Log.e("EAM", "contactData[3]: "+contactData[3]);

                ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
                Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
                builder.withSelection(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + "=?" + " AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=?"+ " AND " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.PROTOCOL + "=?" + " AND " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.DATA + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(rawContactID), ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, String.valueOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.PROTOCOL_SKYPE), String.valueOf(contactData[2])});             
                builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.DATA, newSkypeName);
                ops.add(builder.build());
                // Update
                try
                {
                    getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
                    Log.e("EAM", "SKYPE NAME SAVED AS: "+newSkypeName);
                    savedContactName = contactData[3];
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:savedContactSkype();");
                        }
                    });
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```